# Qt VS Tools Generating Incorrect MOC Command

Tags: qt

I've been struggling all afternoon to track down an issue with the Qt VS Tools in Visual Studio 2013. I'm trying to update an existing .vcxproj file that used a home-grown mechanism for generating MOC, UIC, etc. files to use the Qt VS Tools mechanism instead.

The problem I'm having is in the MOC command that's getting generated for .h files that include the Q_OBJECT macro. A sample line (reduced for brevity) is here:

```
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">"$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe"  "%(FullPath)" -o ".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_%(Filename).cpp"  "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui" "-I$(NOINHERIT)"</Command>
```

The problem is that NOINHERIT doesn't exist, so the "-I$(NOINHERIT)" gets evaluated to "-I" without a value, and the MOC compiler complains and doesn't generate the MOC file. I've tried cleaning up inherited paths, checking and unchecking the "Inherit from parent or project defaults", and the only change I sometimes see is that it has "-I" without the NOINHERIT macro.

Completely starting over with a new .vcxproj file is beginning to feel like my only hope, but that's a much larger task than I'd like to take since there's a significant number of them with interdependencies that I'd rather not create again.

I'm using the latest Qt VS Tools, which is version 2.3.2. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, five minutes after I post, I found the issue. An included property file had this:

```
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories></AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Rather than this, which solved the problem:

```
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Interestingly, and for what it's worth, this did not work:

```
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` at `project->C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`.

`%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` is added by default, but if for some reason, this is overwrite by mistake, then we will get an error as such.

> Moc'ing XXXXXXX.h...
>    Missing value after '-I'.